# Undefined variable report-content

Tags: wordpress

Soy nuevo por aquí y tengo una pregunta, ojalá puedan ayudarme. Recibido este error del plugin de WordPress report-content

> Notice: Undefined variable: message in /storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/report-content/inc/reports-list.php on line 26

[Este es el archivo en conflicto](https://pastebin.com/keRinfF4)

Comment: La parte de la línea 26 parece correcta. Apunta más bien a un error del plugin y deberías preguntar en el foro de soporte del mismo si no lo has hecho.

Comment: Te comento que ya lo hice pero el mismo no recibe actualizaciones desde hace más de dos años, parece que lo abandonaron. Talvez puedas echarle un ojo, https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/report-content/

Comment: Si no lo actualizan desde hace dos años busca otro plugin. En WP un plugin *estancado*  supone un grave riesgo de seguridad en tu sitio.

Comment: Creo que eso no es una opción por el momento, no hay nada parecido el repositorio de WordPress, pero gracias.

Comment: Ya. Otra opción sería hacer tu propio plugin. Con el tiempo yo terminé haciendo eso por lo mismo, porque en casi todas las actualizaciones tenía problemas parecidos a este.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a bajar la version de PHP del servidor a la 5.6.xx por ejemplo.
Este tipo de errores me ha surgido a veces por utilizar versiones más modernas de PHP.